# nativescript 7 - Live reload is working only once

Tags: nativescript

I've installed latest version on Nativescript as documentation says:
[nativescript Full setup with javascript](https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/ns-setup-os-x)
Everything went fine, so next i did setup my first project: `tns create HelloWorld`

Next i started the project using `npm run ios`
Iphone emulator has started, and when i made first change to text label, i saw that app refresh, but on second change conosle said that project is refreshed, but no changes on app. If i close app and run again, i see live reload only works once and next it igores any changes. My question is how to fix this.